# Plot explicit cdf instead of ecdf in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, cumulative-distribution-function

I have adjusted the parameters (lambda, mu, sigma) for a mixture of two normals fitted to my data. Now I would like to plot the cdf of this model using the explicit function instead of the ecdf. Is there any way to do this or I do I have to simulate data so then I can use again ecdf?

The explicit function is something like:

```
ipc_values_EM\$lambda[1] * dnorm(x, ipc_values_EM\$mu[1], ipc_values_EM\$sigma[1]) 
+
ipc_values_EM\$lambda[2] * dnorm(x, ipc_values_EM\$mu[2], ipc_values_EM\$sigma[2])
```

(as you can note, is the mixture of two normals different mus and different sigmas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the title of the function `ecdf()` says, it is empirical and only runs on samples.

If you want the exact cdf of a Gaussian, the function you are looking for is `pnorm()`. Here is a demonstration.

```
x <- seq(from=-5, to=5, by=.1)
y <- pnorm(x)
plot(x, y, type='l')
```

If you replace `dnorm()` by `pnorm()` in your code, and `x` by the range of values you want to take the cdf over you should get the result you are looking for.

Comment: I tried a little different approach but with the same spirit in mind, just used the curve() function and the code is as follows:

curve(ipc_values_EM\$lambda[1] * pnorm(x, ipc_values_EM\$mu[1], ipc_values_EM\$sigma[1]) 
+
ipc_values_EM\$lambda[2] * pnorm(x, ipc_values_EM\$mu[2], ipc_values_EM\$sigma[2]), from=-0.10, to=0.07, add=TRUE, col="blue")

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in using the `distr` package for plotting the theoretical distribution functions for mixture distributions.  Here is a quick example:

```
library(distr)
tmp <- UnivarMixingDistribution( Norm(10,2), Norm(15,1), mixCoeff=c(1,2)/3)
plot(tmp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach works for plotting a `cdf` of a `standard normal`.  It seems to give almost the same answer as `pnorm(x, 0, 1)` with the `standard normal` and also allows the function to be modified.

```
sigma <- 1
mu    <- 0

integrand <- function(x) {(1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(1)^((-1*((x-mu)^2))/(2*(sigma^2))))}

my.cdf <- matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=length(seq(-5,5,0.01)))

m <- 1

for(i in seq(-5,5,by=0.01)){

     my.cdf[m,1] <- i

     my.cdf[m,2] <- as.numeric(integrate(integrand, lower = -5, upper = i)[1])

     m <- m+1

}

plot(my.cdf[,1], my.cdf[,2])

x <- seq(-5,5,0.01)

my.cdf2 <- pnorm(x, 0, 1)

round(my.cdf[,2],5) - round(my.cdf2,5)
```

Here I modify the function to approximate what I suspect you want.  I am not sure whether this gives the solution you are after:

```
myconstant1 <- 0.4
sigma1 <- 1
mu1    <- 0

myconstant2 <- 0.2
sigma2 <- 2
mu2    <- 3

integrand <- function(x) {myconstant1 * ((1/(sigma1*sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(1)^((-1*((x-mu1)^2))/(2*(sigma1^2))))) +
                          myconstant2 * ((1/(sigma2*sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(1)^((-1*((x-mu2)^2))/(2*(sigma2^2))))) }

my.cdf <- matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=length(seq(-5,10,0.01)))

m <- 1

for(i in seq(-5,10,by=0.01)){

     my.cdf[m,1] <- i

     my.cdf[m,2] <- as.numeric(integrate(integrand, lower = -5, upper = i)[1])

     m <- m+1

}

jpeg(file="myplot.jpeg")
plot(my.cdf[,1], my.cdf[,2])
dev.off()
```

[image]